# How to create MultipleView type Recycler-View correctly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

how to create recyclerview with multipe view type. i was tried with my code ,but this is method isnt working actually.

i was got my code from this reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/12192293

How the correctly way to create multiple view type into recycler-view?

**adapter code :**

```
    private static final int THIS_DATE = 0;
    private static final int THIS_DATA = 1;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == THIS_DATE){
            return new DateViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_money_manager_date, parent, false));
        }else{
            return new DataViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_money_manager, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "ResourceType"})
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final MoneyManager moneyManager = moneyManagers.get(position);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        getCurrentBalance();

        getTotalIncome();

        if (getItemViewType(position) == THIS_DATE){
            DateViewHolder dateViewHolder = (DateViewHolder) holder;
            dateViewHolder.textDate.setText(moneyManager.getDate());
        }else{
            DataViewHolder dataViewHolder = (DataViewHolder) holder;
            dataViewHolder.textName.setText(moneyManager.getName());


            if (moneyManager.getExpense() != 0){
                dataViewHolder.textMoney.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("id", "id")).format(moneyManager.getExpense()));
                dataViewHolder.textMoney.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorExpense));
            }else{

                dataViewHolder.textMoney.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("id", "id")).format(moneyManager.getIncome()));
                dataViewHolder.textMoney.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorIncome));
            }
        }
    }

    private void getTotalIncome() {
        long totalIncome = 0;

        for (MoneyManager moneyManager : moneyManagers){
            totalIncome += moneyManager.getIncome();
        }

        moneyManagerFragment.textTotalIncome.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("id","id")).format(totalIncome));
    }

    private void getCurrentBalance() {
        long yourBalance = 0;

        for (MoneyManager moneys : moneyManagers){
            yourBalance += moneys.getIncome() - moneys.getExpense();
        }

        moneyManagerFragment.textMoney.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("id", "id")).format(yourBalance));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moneyManagers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return THIS_DATE;
        }else{
            return THIS_DATA;
        }
    }

    private class DateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textDate;

        public DateViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        }
    }

    private class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textName , textMoney, textDate;
        ImageView imageCategory;

        public DataViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            textMoney = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textIncomeOrExpense);
            imageCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageCategory);
            textDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDateTime);
        }
    }
```

Some help or suggestion will be appreciate, and sorry for bad grammar before

Comment: It's hard to understand what problem are you facing. Perhaps writing your question in your own language and using google translate will be helpful.

Comment: so, i have bugs , when i inserting data ,data would be change to header without show the detail. i think my code was correctly

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Any error message?

Comment: multipleview type . header and detail but in my code this is only show the header